# How to formating URL with strips in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, url

I want to change the URL format from this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/4123/news today in the sea
```

to :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/4123/news-today-in-the-sea
```

**how to change it in Laravel?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper in laravel `str_slug()`

```
$string = str_slug("news today in the sea", "-");
//$string : "news-today-in-the-sea"
```

Comment: how to use in dynamic url?

Comment: @Fazan use a variable instead of `"news today in the sea"`. i dont understand your question

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic str slug you can make function like this, and prepare to add column 'slug' on the table into database

```
public function convertSlugUrl(News $news)
{
    $news->slug = str_slug($news->name);
    $news->save();

    return $news;
}
```

After it you need make route like this

```
Route::get('detailPage/{slug}', function($slug){
$result =   DB::table('news')->where('slug', $slug)->get(); 
     // .... call controller etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic Slug Url, when you add news then create one **column in the database - slug**
and convert name using below laravel helper functions and save in database.

```
$slug= Illuminate\Support\Str::kebab("news today in the sea");
```

The "news-today-in-the-sea" is called kebab case,use laravel helper Directly Str::kebab() as in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-kebab-case